# T-SQL different result between code in stored and same code in query pane

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm working on a procedure that should return a o or a 1, depending on result from parameter calculation (parameters used to interrogate 2 tables in a database).

When I excute that code in a query pane, it gives me the results i'm expecting.
code looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 state, updDate INTO #history
FROM [xxx].[dbo].[ImportHystory]    WHERE (db = 'EB') ORDER BY addDate DESC;

IF (SELECT state FROM #history) = 'O' 
BEGIN       
        SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #process_status
        FROM yyy.dbo.process_status WHERE KeyName = 'eb-importer';

        IF(SELECT s.EndDate FROM #process_status s) IS NOT NULL
            IF (SELECT s.EndDate FROM #process_status s) > (SELECT h.updDate FROM #history h)
                BEGIN
                    IF (SELECT MessageLog from #process_status) IS NOT NULL SELECT 1;
                    ELSE SELECT 0;
                END
            ELSE 
                SELECT  1;
        ELSE
            SELECT 1;
    END
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

I'm in the situation where EndDate from #process_status is null, so the execution returns 1.
Once i put the SAME code in a SP, and pass 'EB' and 'eb-importer' as parameters, it returns 0.

And I exec the procedure with the data from the table right in front of me, so i know for sure that result is wrong.

Inside the procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[can_start_import] (@keyName varchar, @db varchar, @result bit output)
    DECLARE @result bit;
```

and replace every

```
    SELECT {0|1}
```

with

```
    SELECT @result = {0|1}
```

Executed from the Query pane:

```
    DECLARE @result bit;
    EXEC [dbo].[can_start_import] @KeyName = 'eb-importer', @db = 'EB', @result = @result OUTPUT
    SELECT @result AS N'@result'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please post your proc code.

Comment: check if there is something wrong with type and size of the SP parameter.

Comment: How are you capturing the returned value from the SP?  Can you show that code?  It is possible that you are capturing the [return code instead of the result set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You are doing a `top(1)` query without an `order by`. That means SQL Server can pick any row from `table1` that matches the where clause.

If you want to guarantee that the result is the same every time you execute that code you need an `order by` statement that unambiguously orders the rows.

Comment: or rephrase the whole thing to be something like `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` to get rid of those unnecessary temp tables

Comment: I use the order by, i just didn't include it in here.

Comment: @strongmmc Then you should update your question with the code that you are actually executing. The table definitions, including any indexes, constraints etc along with some sample data would also be helpful when figuring out what is happening.

Comment: because of protection policies i can't add more than i already put in the question. I can provide fake data, similar to what i'm working with in order to repropose the problem

Comment: @strongmmc is addate+db unique in importhystory? If not, you still have the same problem. And the query against process_stastus is also missing an order by.

Comment: it doesn't because it doesn't need it. there's a single record for each unique key_name, in that table.

Comment: i managed to delimit the  error. it seems that when i select state from #history it has a char value like it should just in the query pane.
with the same select inside the procedure the value becomes null...

Comment: If key_name is unique you don't need the top(1) on that query. What about history? Do you have an identity column in there? If not add one and use that as the second column in the order by. That way you will have a guaranteed order of rows. @strongmmc

Comment: @Michale Eriksonn you're right, i don't need TOP but i added it just to be safe. i'm not in control of the db so i can't change nothing, i can just interrogate it (apart from adding stored procedures). history source table has an identity field wich is an id (int) self incrementing and it's totally useless in this case. i know there are rows with db = some value and i need to take the single one with the highest date, ckeck its not nullable state and do smtn with it. the key here is : from the pane i get the value, from the procedure i don't.

Comment: @strongmmc you could at least try what I'm suggesting to see if it makes a difference. If you do that and it still is the same I will delete this answer.

Comment: if i sounded  rude, i apologize. anyhow it's midnight here so i'll call it a day. in the morning i'll try adding the identity in the query. thanks for founding the time to answer!

Comment: @strongmmc No worries.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently 2 things needed to be done:

- set the length of the varchar parameter with a higher length,
- filter with ' like ' instead of ' = ' for god knows what reason

Now it work as i expected to do, but i still don't get the different results between the query pane and the procedure if i use the equal...